# Update Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to update 2 columns of a table, I've echoed the $sql1, it is showing dates what I want(y-m-d) to insert into database, but when I fire the query, dates were updated as 0000-00-00 (y-m-d) in database.

output of `echo $sql1`

```
UPDATE member SET 
  reg_date='2014-03-05' AND expiry='2014-03-06'
  WHERE bill_id='9'
```

following are my query statements--

```
$sql1="UPDATE member SET 
         reg_date='$date1' AND expiry='$date' 
         WHERE bill_id='$_REQUEST[bid]'";
mysql_query($sql1,$con)or die(mysql_error());
```

Can you please solve the error?

Comment: The syntax is not right. `reg_date='$date1' and expiry='$date'` should be `reg_date='$date1', expiry='$date'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is to separate by commas in your `SET` clause.

```
UPDATE table 
  SET field1 = 1, field2 = 2, field3 = 3 
  WHERE field = 1
```

In your case:

```
$sql1="UPDATE member 
  SET reg_date='$date1', expiry='$date' 
  WHERE bill_id='" . $_REQUEST[bid] . "'";
mysql_query($sql1,$con)or die(mysql_error());
```

I also separated out your `WHERE` clause, as it looks as if it may have trouble parsing the string.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate your values with commas, not with and

```
$sql1="update member set reg_date='$date1', expiry='$date' where bill_id='$_REQUEST[bid]'";
```

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable response. I've tried it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql1="update member set reg_date='$date1', expiry='$date' where bill_id='$_REQUEST[bid]'";
```

You should not use "and" to separate values, instead you can use "commas" to separate values.